# How to select data using where clause on timestamp in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to get data from a Bigquery table. In where clause i want to get the data on the basis of year like 2020. I am using EXTRACT(part FROM timestamp_expression [AT TIME ZONE timezone])

[image]

Query Looks like

```
  with input as (Select created_at as timestamp_value,user_id from `seraphic-spider-311810.Demo.table2`)
SELECT 
EXTRACT(Year FROM timestamp_value AT TIME ZONE "UTC") as year_value
FROM Input
where year_value like '2020%';
```

Answer (score 3):

use `WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM timestamp_value) = 2020`

Comment: Unrecognized name: year_value at [5:25]

Comment: with input as (Select created_at as timestamp_value,user_id from `seraphic-spider-311810.Demo.Table`)
SELECT 
EXTRACT(Year FROM timestamp_value AT TIME ZONE "UTC") as year_value
FROM Input
where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM year_value) = 2020;

Comment: it is `timestamp_value` - not `year_value`

Comment: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [5:7]

Comment: `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM timestamp_value)` returns INT64, so I don't see how this can be an issue - unless you have some typo(s). make sure you don't use `'2020'` - but you do use `2020`

Comment: Is there any simple way like  SELECT DISTINCT cust_id
      FROM            dataset
      WHERE           month(transaction_date)=1
      AND             year(transaction_date)=2016

Comment: sure! use `extract(month from transaction_date) = 1` meantime, consider voting up and accept the answer if it helped with your original question  :o)